# Print a document like a PDF?

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I need to create a function to get the data from database and print in a PDF file.

Does anyone has any idea how to help me?

I have tried this way, from an example before, but i have some problem with the procedures, and also i am not sure if is the right  way.

So i would use some help and website or tutorials to solve this issues.

```
Private Sub buildEsamelaboratorio(ByVal operations As DataOperations, ByVal body As IBand, ByVal cc As CartellaClinica, ByVal idCC As String, ByVal idRicovero As String)

    Try
        Dim sql As New SQL(operations.getDBMS)

        Dim Esamelaboratorio As New DataTable

        If operations.CHECK_IFEXIST_IDCC_ESAME_L(idCC) Or operations.CHECK_IFEXIST_IDCC_ESAME_LLN_ULN(idCC) Then
            Esamelaboratorio = operations.GET_CC_TEST_LABORATORY(idCC)

        End If

        Dim tableEsameLaboratorio As New DataTable
        tableEsameLaboratorio.Columns.Add(New DataColumn)
        Dim anamnesiEoUtils As New AnamnesiEoInit

        Dim disciplineDegenza = anamnesiEoUtils.getDisciplineDegenza(idRicovero, operations, cc)
        Dim campiEsameLaboratorio = anamnesiEoUtils.getEsameLaboratorio(disciplineDegenza, operations, True)   'just to test cause the procedure is the wrong one
        If Esamelaboratorio IsNot Nothing Then
            For Each DESCRIPTION As String In campiEsameLaboratorio
                Dim dictionaryRecords As List(Of CN_TEST_LABORATORY_MODEL_ITEMS) = operations.GET_EsameLaboratorio(DESCRIPTION)
                Dim table As DataTable
                table = New DataTable()
                Dim row As DataRow = table.NewRow()
                If Not table.Columns.Count = 0 Then
                    Dim hasDESCRIPTION As Boolean
                    hasDESCRIPTION = True
                    row(0) = hasDESCRIPTION


                    If dictionaryRecords.Count > table.Columns.Count - 1 Then

                        Dim numberOfNewColumns = dictionaryRecords.Count - (table.Columns.Count - 1) 'Excluding label column

                        For index As Integer = 1 To numberOfNewColumns

                            table.Columns.Add(New DataColumn)
                        Next
                    End If
                    Dim rowHasValues As Boolean = False
                    For index As Integer = 0 To dictionaryRecords.Count - 1

                        Dim value As String

                        If EsamelaboratorioTypes.Esamelaboratorio Then

                            '               value = getEsamelaboratorioEoCellValue(Esamelaboratorio, dictionaryRecords(index), sql)

                        Else
                            value = ""
                        End If
                        If value <> "" AndAlso value <> "NO" AndAlso value <> "-" Then

                            If hasDESCRIPTION Then

                                row(index + 1) = value

                            Else

                                row(index) = value
                            End If

                            rowHasValues = True
                        End If
                    Next
                    If rowHasValues Then
                        table.Rows.Add(row)
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim log As New Log
        log.writeLog("cartellaClinicaReport", ex, "idCC: " + idCC)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Why does some var have an english name while others has an italian name?

Comment: Wich DB are you using?

Comment: cause is an italian project

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help you:

First we have to get the data from the DB, the above function will do that while saving the results in a `DataTable`

```
Private Function GetDataFromDB() As DataTable
    Dim your_connection_string As String = "INSERT_YOUR_CONNECTION_STRING_HERE!"
    Dim your_query As String = "INSERT_YOUR_QUERY_HERE!"
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using myConn As New OracleClient.OracleConnection(your_connection_string)
        myConn.Open()
        Using myCmd As New OracleClient.OracleDataAdapter(your_query, myConn)
            myCmd.Fill(dt) 'Fill the DataTable with the query results
        End Using
        myConn.Close()
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function
```

As you can see the above function returns a DataTable value, this is why we are going to call it inside the next function!

The function below will print in a PDF file the data inside a DataGridView. So we are going to bind the `DataTable` as a `DataGridView.DataSource`

```
Private Sub CreatePdf(ByVal dt As DataTable)
    Dim DataGridView1 As New DataGridView
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    'Creating iTextSharp Table from the DataTable data
    Dim pdfTable As New PdfPTable(DataGridView1.ColumnCount)
    pdfTable.DefaultCell.Padding = 3
    pdfTable.WidthPercentage = 30
    pdfTable.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT
    pdfTable.DefaultCell.BorderWidth = 1

    'Adding Header row
    For Each column As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns
        Dim cell As New PdfPCell(New Phrase(column.HeaderText))
        'cell.BackgroundColor = New iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(240, 240, 240)
        pdfTable.AddCell(cell)
    Next

    'Adding Data
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
            pdfTable.AddCell(cell.Value.ToString())
        Next
    Next

    'Exporting to PDF
    Dim folderPath As String = "YOUR_SAVING_PATH_HERE"
    If Not Directory.Exists(folderPath) Then
        Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath)
    End If
    Using stream As New FileStream(folderPath & "DataGridViewExport.pdf", FileMode.Create)
        Dim pdfDoc As New Document(PageSize.A2, 10.0F, 10.0F, 10.0F, 0.0F)
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, stream)
        pdfDoc.Open()
        pdfDoc.Add(pdfTable)
        pdfDoc.Close()
        stream.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
```

As you can see the `CreatePdf` has a DataTable parameter, so let's call it when a `button click` event is fired for example:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    CreatePdf(GetDataFromDB())
End Sub
```

As you can se, we are calling a function inside a function. This is because `CreatePdf()` has a DataTable parameter while GetDataFromDB returns a DataTable value!

***N.B.***

In order to make it work, you need to include the following `imports`:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System
Imports iTextSharp.text
Imports iTextSharp.text.api
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO
```

You also have to [add the reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx) to [itextsharp.dll](https://www66.zippyshare.com/v/tz2pZjSt/file.html) and to [System.Data.OracleClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.data.oracleclient.oracleconnection?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: @ShkelzenTarja then use only the CreatePdf function an pass your DataTable as the parameter

Comment: thannk you i create the print function but i have a problem with the part before, like the creation of the table

Comment: @ShkelzenTarja I edited my `GetDataFromDB()` in order to work with Oracle

Comment: for the that i have to use procedures... cause is a big project...i don't know if you got it, what i mean.

Comment: Than use your procedures and fill the `DataTable`. I cannot understand what do you expect from me. I'm not here to do code your program for you, I'm here to help and give some alternatives at your problem. If you get problems while filling your `DataTable`, probably is because the code is a bit messy :/

Comment: @ShkelzenTarja by the way, you asked a function to print your data as a pdf, i gave it to you. what's the problem?

Comment: thank you  @simo i created ,, and it works, but i have  a problem with the code i have posted... plesase write me any email.. shkelzentarja@gmail.com for more...

Comment: @ShkelzenTarja email sent

Comment: i haven't got any email

Comment: can you see my last question? @simo

Comment: Wich one? [show the title...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52477619/show-the-title-near-the-table) or [creating a module...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52363124/creating-a-module-that-make-possible-to-get-the-data-from-database)